# Padding data base on date range join

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset with dates set to the first of each month.
Eg -

| Units | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | 2021-01-01 |
| 37 | 2021-02-01 |
| 47 | 2021-03-01 |

I need to join this on this table :

| Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-12 |
| 2021-02-13 | 2021-02-26 |
| 2021-02-27 | 2021-03-12 |

Now normally I would a right join on this clause -

```
WHERE DATE BETWEEN START DATE AND END DATE
```

...and it works fine, for DATE 2021-02-01. That falls between 2021-01-30 and 2021-02-12.

Similarly, 2021-03-01 date falls between 2021-02-27 and 2021-03-12

HOWEVER! I get null values for Pay Periods with Start Date  2021-02-13 and End Date 2021-02-26. I want the date from Table A  for the month of Feb to be populated for this row too.

I would want the data from Table A, which for Feb (2020-02-01) is 37 units to have two rows, one joined with Start Date 2021-01-30 & End Date 2021-02-12, and the other joined with Start Date 2021-02-13 & End Date 2021-02-26. (Since both Pay Periods fall in February). The result data set should look like this -

| Units | Date | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-15 | 2021-01-29 |
| 37 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-12 |
| 37 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-13 | 2021-02-26 |
| 47 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-02-27 | 2021-03-12 |

This is the query I am using -

```
SELECT * 
  FROM A 
 RIGHT 
  JOIN B
    ON A.DATE BETWEEN B.START DATE AND B.END DATE
```

Comment: That is not MySQL's standard date format.. Are you storing them as `VARCHAR`? Also, [why don't you post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66948571/edit) the full query instead. And if I understand correctly, are you attempting to show the `Start Date` and `End Date` range even though there's no result?

Comment: They are being stored as a date. I manually inputted the dates here, in SQL they are being stored as '2021-02-01'. I would want the data from Table A, which for Feb (2020-02-01) is 37 units to have two rows, one joined with Start Date 2021-01-30 & End Date  2021-02-12, and the other joined with Start Date 2021-02-13 & End Date 2021-02-26. (Since both Pay Periods fall in February)

Comment: In that case, please update your data sample accordingly to prevent misleading.

Comment: Gotcha! Corrected.

Comment: The question is still unclear though.. How about you illustrate how would your expected result look like? And also, please just post a simplified query that you've attempted. That would help in making your question clearer.

Comment: Just edited again. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want this, but with what you have already, I'm pretty sure you can figure this out for yourself!

Comment: From what I can see, you just need to join based on month .. between table A date and table B end date. But I'm curious about the first row in your expected output.. the period of `2021-01-15` to `2021-01-29` was non-existing in table B, how was it generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the date range `2021-01-15` to `2021-01-29` is missing from `Table B` example. If so, this query should be able to return your expected result:

```
SELECT Units, Date, StartDate, EndDate
  FROM tableA a
  LEFT JOIN tableB b
    ON a.Date <= b.EndDate
    AND MONTH(a.Date) = MONTH(b.EndDate)
    ORDER BY b.StartDate
```

Instead of `RIGHT JOIN`, I've swithced to `LEFT JOIN`. Then comparing `Date` from `Table A` with `End Date` from `Table B` with `<=` (smaller than or equal to) and matching `Date` month with `End Date` month using `MONTH()`. With the example provided (inclusive of assumed missing date range), this will return exactly as your expected result.

Here's a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02c027506954489377a8e484693bff57

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY! Thank you so much.